# How to get an edge associated with a vertex point from a Delaunay triangulation?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, edges, delaunay

According to the reference manual of OpenCV, if the point (x,y) of the function:

```
import cv2.cv as cv
a=cv.Subdiv2DLocate(subdiv,(x,y))
```

is a vertex of the Delaunay triangulation represented by `subdiv`, the function does not return an edge, but a tuple that contains a `cvsubdiv2dpoint` structure.

I tried to access the `first` field of the `cvsubdiv2dpoint` structure, but my Python shell crashes and restarts.

How do I get one of the edges associated to this vertex point?

My environment is Ubuntu 12.04, Python 2.7, OpenCV 2.4.4